# How to get the current CRS of a networkx.MultiDiGraph when using OSMnx?

Tags: python, projection, osmnx

I obtained an `osmnx.graph_from_bbox` and cannot find a function to get the current projection (**CRS**). My purpose is to check the CRS of a graph somewhere in my code and decide if it needs to be projected (`osmnx.project_graph`) or leave it as it is. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I obtained an osmnx.graph_from_bbox and cannot find a function to get the current projection (CRS).

As demonstrated in OSMnx's [usage examples](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples) the CRS is defined in the graph attribute dictionary, accessible like `G.graph["crs"]`.

> My purpose is to check the CRS of a graph somewhere in my code and decide if it needs to be projected (osmnx.project_graph) or leave it as it is.

See also OSMnx's [is_projected](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.projection.is_projected) function.